# Безопасность кода

Tags: java

В целом хотелось бы задать вопрос, в широком смысле, как Вы реализуете безопасный код?
  (применение большого количества различных модификаторов доступа, или большое количество внутренних методов закрытых для остального мира которые в свою очередь взаимодействуют с открытыми методами или у Вас есть свои методики сокрытия)

в первую очередь предотвращение нежелательного вмешательства из вне и нарушение нормальной работы кода

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А что Вы вкладываете в понятие безопасного кода?

Comment: если вы под безопасностью подразумеваете возможность влезть в код, то при наличии Unsafe вы вряд ли с этим можете что-то сделать

Comment: Задавать здесь вопросы "в широком смысле" уже опасно. Очень легко нырнуть в пучину холиваров и неконкретики, что у нас закрывают.

Comment: Всё перечисленное в скобках — лишь синтаксический сахар, который обходится как нефиг делать с помощью прямого доступа к памяти процесса